# makefile with files in different directory C++

Tags: c++, makefile

My current makefile worked fine. But since then some files have been moved to a different new 'Common' directory. So what should my makefile look like to build this scenario. Currently (cut down version pasted here):

```
SERVER_OLIST = file1.o file2.o file3.o $(CRYPT_LIST)

INCLUDES =  
LIBRARIES =  -lpthread -lrt `mysql_config --cflags` `mysql_config --libs`
DEFINES = 
VERSION_DEFINES = -DBUILD_VERSION='"1.3.0"'
COMPILE_OPTIONS = -posix -fexceptions $(DEFINES)
LINK_OPTIONS = -posix

all: loraserver loracmd

loraserver: testbuild
    cp $^ $@

.PHONY: updateBuildTime
updateBuildTime:
    rm -f BuildVersion.o

testbuild: updateBuildTime $(SERVER_OLIST)
    g++ -o $@ $(SERVER_OLIST) $(LINK_OPTIONS) $(LIBRARIES)
```

and so I tried this with server list changed to be:

```
SERVER_OLIST = file1.o ../Common/file2.o file3.o $(CRYPT_LIST)
```

but when it tried to build it said:
'No rule to make target ../Common/file2.o needed by 'testbuild'
Rather than rewrite the whole makefile is there a way of specifying different dirs for different files ?

Comment: all the other answers to this questions would require me to totally rewrite the makefile or create other makefiles in other directories from scratch - and I don't to create libraries in these other directories.

Comment: You'll have to provide more details, because this works for me.  Are you sure that there's a file `../Common/file2.cpp`?  Is that really your entire makefile?

Comment: ok I added a new line called COMMON_OLIST = ../Common/File2.cpp and added this to the testbuild: line with $(notdir $(COMMON_OLIST)) and this worked. However I am unsure about $(CRYPT_LIST). Do i need to add this to the end of COMMON_O_LIST now ?